# Upgrading from webpack 2.1.0 to Webpack 4.12.0 has broken our build, why?

Tags: javascript, html, webpack, webpack-4

I'll start by saying I am a webpack noob so any help is much appreciated.

So

My layout for the Js bundles are that we have two bundles:

```
bundle.js
tablesbundle.js
```

bundle.js contains all our pages standard javascript.
tablesbundle.js contains the datatables.net library.

Now in our old project we used webpack 2.1.0 and all we needed to do was reference bundle.js on our layout file and reference tablesbundle.js on any pages that needed to make use of datatables.net, then in our bundle.js any page that called to create a datatable would be fine and working.

However after moving to webpack 4.12.0 this no longer works, it doesn't pick up the datatables initialiser method found within tablesbundle.js, the only code in tablesbundle.js is:

```
require("datatables.net");
```

Now if i move that line into bundle.js it works fine but we don't want datatables on every page, it appears that our bundled js files are not communicating across bundles but they were however in the previous version.

If anyone can explain or help that would be great.

-- Config File --

```
 module.exports = {
    entry: {
        bundle: "./Scripts/index.js",
        libraries: './Scripts/libraries.js',
        datatablesbundle: "./Scripts/tablesBundle.js"
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [
                    MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    'css-loader'
                ],
            },
            {
                test: /\.sass$|\.scss$/,
                use: [
                    MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    {
                        loader: 'css-loader',
                        options: {},
                    },
                    { loader: 'postcss-loader' },
                    { loader: 'sass-loader' },
                ],
            },
            {
                test: /\.(jpg|png)$/,
                use: 'file-loader?name=[path][name].[hash].[ext]'
            }
        ],
    },


    plugins: getPlugins(),
    output: {
        path: BUILD_DIR,
        filename: '[name].js'
    },
    //optimization: {
    //    splitChunks: {
    //        chunks: 'all'
    //    }
    //},

    resolve: {
        modules: ["web_modules", "node_modules"],
        alias: {
            jquery: "jquery/src/jquery",
            'picker': 'pickadate/lib/picker'
        }
    }
}

    function getPlugins() {

        var isProd = (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production');

        var plugins =
            [
                new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
                    filename: "[name].css"
                }),

                new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
                    "window.$": "jquery",
                    $: "jquery",
                    jQuery: "jquery",
                    Popper: "popper.js"
                })
            ];

        if (isProd) {
            plugins.push(
                new UglifyJSPlugin({
                    output: {
                        comments: false,
                        beautify: true,
                        sourceMap: true
                    }
                }));

            plugins.push(
                new OptimizeCssAssetsPlugin({
                    assetNameRegExp: /\.(css|scss|sass)$/,
                    cssProcessorOptions: { discardComments: { removeAll: true } }
                }));

        }

        return plugins;
    }
```

Comment: would be better if you could share the webpack.config.js file

Comment: done @AseemUpadhyay

Comment: probably it is not recognizing jquery globally. Try adding ProviderPlugin

Comment: @PlayMa256 It does recognise Jquery globally, the thing is I want the tables bundle to be recognised globally but not loaded on every page